# Unable to find BLAS functions mentioned in documentation

Tags: c, blas

I am currently trying to use some BLAS functions. I see the documentation and know what I want to use, but the described functions are nowhere in the actual source code in BLAS. I just don't get it.

I am trying to find blas_xmax_val. This is mentioned in the [documentation](http://www.netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/blas-report.pdf) on page 42. However, I do not see the function anywhere in the source folder.

If anyone has used BLAS before, please can you tell me what's going on here? Where am I supposed to look for it? It's not even mentioned in cblas.h.

This is not the only function with this problem. I see many functions mentioned in the documentation, but not in the source folder.

Please help!

Comment: where is your blas coming from?

Comment: Hi, I got my BLAS from blas.tgz and blast-forum/cblas.tgz as mentioned on the page http://www.netlib.org/blas/

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the report of a technical forum that's recommending changes for BLAS that were just never adopted.

The only BLAS maximum functions I'm aware of are the `IxAMAX()` (x in {S,D,C,Z}) family, which return the index of the first occurrence of the maximum value.

Comment: Okay, that's new to me. So where is the *actual* list of functions that *were* implemented? Right now all I can do is look at the names of the functions listed in the cblas.h file I have, and guess which one might do what I need, and confirm it/try finding out another function after seeing the actual description in the src file. This is so absurd and inefficient. Isn't there a documentation of the existing functions, rather than the functions they wanted? Also, how do I hit enter to have different paragraphs in my response? If I do that, it just 'clicks' on 'Add Comment'

Comment: All the Fortran reference implementations are linked here individually, so it is a complete list: http://www.netlib.org/blas/

Answer (score 1):

The paper you point to is documentation for a code library created by its authors, and not a standard part of the C language. You have to get the code from them and install it, or find someone who has already done that.  The code is freely available at http://netlib.org/blas/

A better-known library for doing this sort of thing is GSL, which might be easier to find an install (it's already installed on many Unix-like systems). http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

Comment: The claim that the GSL is "better-known" than the BLAS is highly suspect.

Comment: GSL includes an implementation of BLAS. Perhaps "widely installed and used" would be a better description.

Comment: ... but there are lots of installations of the BLAS outside of the GSL as well, so the BLAS is necessarily more "widely installed".

Comment: Fair enough. My general impression though is that BLAS is well known to mathematicians, whereas GSL is better known to programmers.  Being a programmer, I'm a bit biased.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I did download the blas.tgz and cblas.tgz mentioned on http://www.netlib.org/blas/. I installed them correctly, and am able to use the functions that I see in the src folder of CBLAS. However, not all the functions in the documentation are there in the actual library.